# Air demand for powder fluidization system

Tags: pneumatic

I need a good estimate of the air demand for a system to fluidizde a powder. We a have silo with a 60° cone and a rotary cell feeder attached to the opening in the cone. The powder (fine powdered activated coal) shall be fluidized by blowing some compresses air into it. Perrys chemical engineering handbook gives some tables and nomogram for full fluzidization (air velocity of 0.15 - 6 m/s over free area of silo). However, I really only need fluidization near the walls of the cone, so I should be able to get away with less.

Silo diameter is 3-4m, mass flow rate up to 60kg/h

How do I estimate the air need for fluidization?

Comment: Given the wide range of velocity you specify that you found - I think you will be experimenting... And you specify "up to 60kg/hr so what is the lower limit - zero?

Comment: misunderstanding. Perry described the velocities encountered over a wide range of fully fluididized bed processes, which is a different beast.

Comment: How are you going to get the air to follow the wall?  Wall or whole bed what matters is velocity.  You can test with a small container.  It is tricky to fluidize small particles.

Comment: Unless you plan to cast the powder, are you aware of the enourmous compressor needed to sustain long term operation if you need to spray it? Or that you need to keep repressurizing the silo frequently, which can take up enourmous amounts of time with a smaller compressor.